# Scraping availability of the product

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, screen-scraping

My goal is to scrape some data if the product available or not.

At present I am using the following:

=importxml (B2,//*[@id="product-controls"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwlA.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwlA.png))

Unfortunately, i am receiving an error. Here is the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11OJvxRRIXJolpi2UttmNIOArAdwh1qeZhjqczlVI8oc/edit#gid=1531110146

As an example, I want to get the data from the url https://radiodetal.com.ua/mikroshema-5m0365r-dip8

and Xpath should be from here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

got the formula
=importxml (B2,"//div[@class='stock']")